# Unidentified growth in purple cabbage

Tags: cabbage

I cut open a purple cabbage and there are some strange sort of greyish, slightly yellowish sprout-like masses inside. Is this normal? I saw another [post on this stack with a similar question,](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107381/what-is-this-yellow-and-white-mass-inside-my-red-cabbage) but my 'masses' look more...moldy, I guess? Is it immature flower shoots as the other post says? 
Is it safe to eat this cabbage? Thank you in advance
[image: cabbage growth]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this yellow and white mass inside my red cabbage?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/107381/what-is-this-yellow-and-white-mass-inside-my-red-cabbage)

Comment: Well it seems somewhat similar, but as I said, my 'masses' seem much darker, almost moldy ... The other post looks ...fresh. it's just hard to tell. Can you see my image?

Comment: You say they look moldy, the picture look moldy and rotting to me too... is there any other smell/texture/anything that is inconsistent with mold or rot?

Comment: No, not at all - seems fine otherwise

Comment: I think what it might be is indeed the 'immature flowering' that the other post concluded, but that this head must be a bit older, and the sprouting flowers have started to decay just a bit...not quite rotten, but dying. Does that seem feasible?

Comment: At any rate, I've let the head go, but thanks for the replies. Still, such an odd thing. Could not find much other info on it anywhere besides the one other post on this stack. Would still be interested in other thoughts on the subject tho...cheers!

Comment: I'm also quite sure it's the same thing - cannot say why the flowers rotted while the other part looked intact, but that happens in vegetables every now and then, that some parts get sick or spoil while others are still OK.